I have a query that outputs 5-6 different counts with union statements. Is there a way I can add row labels to each one?
The code snippet looks like this
(select count)
union
(select count)
union
(select count)
union
(select count)
union
(select count)

And the output is:
Count
291
3563
44
1
246
8123.

Is there a way I can add row labels? For instance, I would like the end output to be:
Col1.                    Col2.

'Current Revenue'        291

'Current Sales'          3563

And so forth. Is there a fastest/cleanest way to do this?
Thank you!
I tried doing a with and as CTE.

You could just add a label within each select - something like (SELECT 'Current Revenue' AS Col1, COUNT(<your expression here>) AS Col2) UNION (SELECT 'Current Sales' AS Col1, COUNT(...) AS Col2) UNION ... etc

Yes, pretty much exactly as you've written. select 'table1' as i_came_from, some_field from table1 union all select 'table2' as i_came_from, some_field from table2 . Note the UNION ALL, minor thing but since the string is going to prevent any duplicates might as well not have UNION check for them.

You can add a string literal to each query.
Side note: since you don't want to remove duplicates (and with those labels, presumably, there should be no duplicates), you can use union all instead of union for a slightly better performance:
SELECT 'Current Revenue', COUNT(*)
FROM   revenue
WHERE  ....
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Current Sales', COUNT(*)
FROM   sales
WHERE  ...
-- And so on


Thank you so much! I knew it was something simple that I was forgetting. Cheers!
